# Proof verification: $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ with $\int_{\alpha}^\beta f=0$ for any $a \le \alpha <\beta \le b$ then $f \equiv 0$ in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Show that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and for each $\alpha,\beta$, $a\le\alpha<\beta\le b$,
> $$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx=0$$
> then $f$ is identically zero on $[a,b]$.

My solution: assume, by contradiction, that $f$ is not identically zero on $[a,b]$, that is there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) \ne 0$; for now, I assume $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $f(x_0)>0$.

Then, by continuity, there exists $r>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in(x_0-r,x_0+r)$ and so, again by continuity and the fact that $f(x_0)>0$, it is
$$\int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r}f(x)dx>0$$
But by hypothesis for each $\alpha,\beta$, $a\le\alpha<\beta\le b$,
$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx=0$$
So $\int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r}f(x)dx>0$ contradicts the hypothesis that for each $\alpha,\beta$, $a\le\alpha<\beta\le b$ it is $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx=0$.

The proof doesn't change if $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$ (I must take respectively a right neighborhood or a left neighborhood of $x_0$) or if $f(x_0)>0$ (in this case I will have a negative integral in $(x_0-r,x_0+r)$), so my assumption was WLOG and so the theorem is proved in all possible cases.

Is this proof valid? My textbook uses a mean value theorem for integrals to prove this, so I am not sure if my proof is valid as well.

Comment: The proof looks good. However, you are using that $f(x) > 0$ on $(x_0-r, x_0+r)$ implies that $\int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r} f(x) \mathrm{d}x > 0$, which is not false, but may lead to the proof being marked incomplete. I would replace the "exists $r >0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for any ..." part by "exists $r>0$ such that $f(x)> f(x_0)/2$ for any ...".

Comment: You definitely need the extra step that Carlo offers, at least if this is a first course for you.  If you prefer to use a hammer rather than a scalpel for this remember that  $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$ at any point at which an integrable function $f$ is continuous.